# dplyr. Spectral (reflectance) dataframe. Average all spectral values based on a single attribute . R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, average

I have  a dataframe which is made of 5 attributes (e.g. Plot, weight, date etc) plus 2000 spectral values (different wavelengths). Thus,  there around 2005 columns.

For these columns, there are 120 measurements (24 objects * measured 5 times). I am keen to average the reflectance (wavelenghts) values (2000 columns) based on a attribute (i.e. plot).

I am thinking about using dplyr package and a pipeline:

```
DF &>%
   group_by(Plot) %>%
   aggregate(... *I am stuck here*
```

End goal is to have a dataframe with 2005 columns, 24 rows (each row consisting of the original metadata + the average value for each wavelength*based on the plot number).

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5892059) for example with `dput()` You don't have to include all your columns, but the structure should be visible

Answer (score 0):

For a similar task, I usually use the `summarize_all` function from dplyr.
You need to drop all columns that cannot be averaged (like if your replicates have different dates), `group_by` the remaining metadata.
Something like :

```
DF %>%
  select(-Date) %>% # remove those metadata columns that cannot be averaged
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  summarize_all(mean)
```